# Foundation6 responsive navigation

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Would really welcome some help with my navbar. I'm trying to achieve what I consider the most obvious setup. Dropdown menus on larger screens and drilldowns on smaller ones. I have a pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgKOJJ) but there are bullet marks that should not be there, and the menu opens horizontally (I want it vertically) on larger screens.

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="nav-menu" data-hidefor="medium">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title player-controls">Brand
    </div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="nav-menu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="top-bar-left show-for-medium">
            Brand
        </div>

        <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
                <li class="has-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Item</a>
                    <ul class="vertical submenu" data-submenu>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Item</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The menu does open vertically on a large screen?

Comment: That's weird, it did not do that when I posted the question. OK, but still have lots of CSS issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure about the vertical menu issue as the pen works fine for me. Regarding the errant bullet points, you are missing some essential classes. For the site title, you're using an `li` without the surrounding `ul` element. Add a `ul` with a class of `menu` around the title to fix that problem:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
</ul>
```

The same `menu` class is missing for the sub menu:

```
<ul class="vertical submenu menu" data-submenu>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>                        
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's an updated [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeExgO)

Comment: Annoyingly when I copy your code over to my project, the menu starts opening to the side again. It's enough to drive you crazy. Thanks anyway

Comment: No probs. If it works in the example, the problem may be with one of your custom css or javascript files.